# Restrict Return Type of Generic Delegate Irrespective of Parameters

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I'm trying to restrict the return type of a generic delegate without specifying the parameter signature, and I don't know how to do this, or if it is even possible.

How can I do this or is it impossible?

My research has come up dry.  Some pseudo-C# code would probably help steer you toward what I'm trying to do:

```
public class SomeClass< T, U > where T : Delegate // returning U
{
    private someDelegate;

    public SomeClass( T someDelegate )
    {
        this.someDelegate = someDelegate;
    }

    public U Run()
    {
        return someDelegate.DynamicInvoke();
    }
}
```

... Elsewhere

```
public delegate string aDelegate();

public static string SayHi()
{
    return "Hello!";
}

aDelegate greeter = SayHi;

var something = new SomeClass< aDelegate, string>( greeter );

Console.WriteLine( something.Run() ); // Should write "Hello" to the console.
```

I know this is a rather contrived pseudo example.  I aim for a more involved usage, of course.  I'm trying to write a console menu class that would associate a list of given menu options with actions that would fire depending on what option the user chooses.  Right now, it just returns the string the user chose from the menu.  What I'd like be able to do is return what--if anything--the associated method returns.  This could perhaps be returned *with* the user chosen option string in a tuple...  But, I figured this mini-example just cut straight to the technical hurdle I'm experiencing.

Thanks!

Comment: What if the delegate has parameters? You just called `DynamicInvoke` with no parameters.

Comment: And what is the purpose of `SomeClass` anyway? Can't you just store an instance of whatever delegate type you use?

Comment: That's a good question, @Sweeper.  Now you've got me wondering if there's a way to thread parameters through.  But, let's suppose, even, that all the delegates had no parameters, but could all return the same type, including void.  The purpose of `SomeClass` is to be a much contrived, but far less lengthy example with which to frame my question.

Comment: @Sweeper This quote, "I know this is a rather contrived pseudo example. I aim for a more involved usage, of course." states that there is other work done in the class that is elided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET already defines a generic delegate that returns the generic argument as it's result, `Func<T>`.  You don't even need to define it.

```
public class SomeClass<U>
{
    private Func<U>;

    public SomeClass(Func<U> someDelegate)
    {
        this.someDelegate = someDelegate;
    }

    public U Run()
    {
        return someDelegate();
    }
}
```

There's no real useful reason to allow a user of the type to provide any arbitrary delegate of the same signature.  Really I'd advise you to avoid using any delegates in your code other than `Func` and `Action` (with various different numbers of generic arguments) whenever possible, as it's just creating a hassle to do so.  I would consider it a reasonable restriction on any caller that has a delegate of a different type but the same signature to simply convert it to a `Func<T>` anyway, it's not like it's even a difficult conversion for them.

Comment: Thanks, Servy.  I'm too low rep to upvote.  Given the laxer constraint of supposing no parameters, this works.  With a passed in delegate type returning a U but having an potentially arbitrary parameter signature, this would not work.  As Sweeper pointed out, I'd need a way to thread the parameters through to the invocation, though.

Comment: @DavidClark And you should most certainly not do that.  It's not useful to accept a delegate with parameters if the caller is going to be providing the parameters themselves.  If they want to call a function with parameters they provide, it's trivial for them to write a parameterless method that calls whatever method(s) they want with whatever parameters they have.

Comment: that (your last comment) is how I’m presently doing it now.  I suppose I just went down a rabbit hole looking for “better”, only to learn what I already have is the accepted answer. 

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use `Func<T>` (as Servy suggests), e.g. if you have a custom delegate of your own that you want to be passed with type-safety, then perhaps you can make your custom delegate generic with respect to its return type. Then you can do it this way:

```
public delegate T MyDelegate<T>();

public class Foo<T>
{
    private readonly MyDelegate<T> _delegate;

    public Foo(MyDelegate<T> handler)
    {
        _delegate = handler;
    }

    public T Bar()
    {
        return _delegate();
    }
}
```